Linear functionals $g, f_1, f_2,...$ on $V$ such that $\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} \ker(f_n) \subset \ker(g)$, but $g \notin \text{span}(\{f_1, f_2,...\})$
I am trying to come up with an example of a vector space $V$ and linear functionals $g, f_1, f_2,\ldots$ on $V$ such that I get $\bigcap_{n = 1}^{\infty} \ker(f_n) \subset \ker(g)$, but $g \notin \text{span}(\{f_1, f_2,\ldots\})$. Because it is indexed by $\mathbb{N}$, I have some potential vector spaces in mind, but I am not sure how I could define my linear operators so that I get the desired result. I was thinking about taking either $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}$, i.e. the space of all real sequences, or I was also thinking about $c_{00}(\mathbb{N})$, i.e. the set of all real sequences that is nonzero for finitely many $n \in \mathbb{N}$. With either one of these vector spaces in mind, what kind of linear functionals could I make out of this? Appreciate the help.

Let $V$ be the space of polynomials with real coefficients, and let the $f_i$ be the linear functionals given by $f_i(x^j) = \delta_{ij}$ (Kronecker's delta) extended linearly.
A polynomial lies in $\cap_{n=1}^{\infty}\ker(f_n)$ if and only if every coefficient is $0$, i.e., $\cap_{n=1}^{\infty}\ker(f_n) = \{0\}$, so it is contained in the kernel of any linear functional.
Now let $g$ be the functional mapping the polynomial $p(x)$ to $p(1)$. If $i_1\lt \cdots\lt i_k$ and $a_1,\ldots,a_k$ are real numbers, then
$$(a_1f_{i_1}+\cdots+a_kf_{i_k})(x^{i_k+1}) = 0 \neq 1 = g(x^{i_{k}+1})$$
so $g\notin\mathrm{span}(\{f_1,f_2,\ldots\})$.
Of course, this example can be turned into one with $V=c_{00}(\mathbb{N})$, as this is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}[x]$ as a real vector space.

A slightly stronger example can be given. Namely,  the condition  $$\bigcap_{k=1}^\infty  \ker \phi_k\subset \ker \psi $$ does not imply that $\psi  $ can be represented as $\psi =\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k\phi_k$ for some coefficients $a_k,$ so that $\sum |a_k|\|\phi_k\|<\infty.$ An example follows.
Let $V=C[0,1]$ and $\psi_k(f)=f(r_k),$ where $\{r_k\}_{k=1}^\infty $ consists of all  rational numbers in $(0,1],$ and $\psi(f)=f(0).$ Then the intersection of the kernels of $\phi_k$ is trivial, hence contained in $\ker\psi.$ However $\psi$ is not equal to $\sum a_k\phi_k$ where $\sum |a_k|<\infty.$ Indeed, assume for a contradiction that $$ f(0)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_kf(r_k)$$ For fixed $0<\delta<1$ let $0\le f_\delta(x)\le 1,$ $f_\delta(0)=1$ and   $f_\delta (x)=0$  for $x\ge \delta>0.$ Then $$1=\psi(f_\delta)=\sum_{0<r_k<\delta}a_kf_\delta(r_k)\le \sum_{0<r_k<\delta}|a_k|$$ The RHS tends to $0$ when $\delta\to 0^+,$ which leads to a contradiction.
